# How to reverse the table that comes from SQL query which already includes ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Here is my query:

```
SELECT TOP 8 id, rssi1, date
FROM history
WHERE (siteName = 'CCL03412') 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

This the result:

[image]

How can I reverse this table based on date (Column2) by using SQL?

Comment: what about : `SELECT TOP 8 id, rssi1, date
FROM history
WHERE (siteName = 'CCL03412') 
ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly: He doesnt want the top 8 order by date desc, He wants the top 8 ordered by id desc and these top 8 should be ordered by Column2.

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly, it gives the same table

Comment: @TimSchmelter, that's right

Comment: @TimSchmelter then as I mentioned below this should do the trick: `select * from (SELECT TOP 8 id, rssi1, date
FROM history
WHERE (siteName = 'CCL03412') 
ORDER BY id DESC ) aa order by aa.date DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the first query to get the matching ids, and use them as part of an `IN` clause:

```
SELECT id, rssi1, date
FROM history
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT TOP 8 id
    FROM history
    WHERE (siteName = 'CCL03412') 
    ORDER BY id DESC
)
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use a sub-query. If you apply a `TOP` clause the nested `ORDER BY` is allowed:

```
SELECT X.* FROM(
  SELECT TOP 8 id, Column1, Column2
  FROM dbo.History
  WHERE (siteName = 'CCL03412') 
  ORDER BY id DESC) X
ORDER BY Column2
```

[Demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213252%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> The SELECT query of a subquery is always enclosed in parentheses. It
>   cannot include a COMPUTE or FOR BROWSE clause, and **may only include an
>   ORDER BY clause when a TOP clause is also specified**.

[**Subquery Fundamentals**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

didn't run it, but i think it should go well

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT id, rssi1, date, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS Rank
    FROM history
    WHERE (siteName = 'CCL03412')
)
SELECT id, rssi1, date
FROM cte
WHERE Rank <= 8
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below :

```
select * from (SELECT TOP 8 id, rssi1, date
FROM history
WHERE (siteName = 'CCL03412') 
ORDER BY id DESC ) aa order by aa.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not run this but i think it will work. Execute and let me know if you face error

select id, rssi1, date from (SELECT TOP 8 id, rssi1, date
FROM history
WHERE (siteName = 'CCL03412') 
ORDER BY id DESC) order by date ;

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1. 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.